# How do I update a list item using REST and Data.js?

Tags: javascript, splistitem, rest, odata

I want to write a simple SP hosted app that edits a single list item in a list in the app web. Getting the list item collection is fine. Then I want to pass the result to a function that changes the title of the first item and then send the updated object to the list using a MERGE request.

However, Data.js throws an exception with the message "HTTP bad request".

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var defaultClient = OData.defaultHttpClient;
var spClient = {
    request: function (request, success, error) {
        request.headers = {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "If-Match": "*"
        };

        return defaultClient.request(request, success, error);
    }
}
OData.defaultHttpClient = spClient;

OData.read({
    requestUri: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('AppTest')/items?$select=Title",
},
function (data) {
    console.dir(data);

    changeTitle(data.results);
});

function changeTitle(results) {
    var id = results[0].__metadata.id;
    results[0].Title = "new title";

    //Error 400 Bad Request https://path/to/dev/site/DatajsTest/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('AppTest')/items(1546e07a-4c37-43fb-9725-b561773eb53a)
    OData.request({
        requestUri: 'https://path/to/dev/site/DatajsTest/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('AppTest')/items(1546e07a-4c37-43fb-9725-b561773eb53a',
        method: "MERGE",
        data: results[0]
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Do not update your post to make it work, post an answer with the working code instead. That way we keep the original issue visible for future readers :)

Comment: @RobertLindgren done

Comment: Terrific, looks great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When updating a list item you should use the uri from the metdata of the list item you want to edit `results[i].__metadata.uri`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var defaultClient = OData.defaultHttpClient;
var spClient = {
    request: function (request, success, error) {
        request.headers = {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "If-Match": "*"
        };

        return defaultClient.request(request, success, error);
    }
}
OData.defaultHttpClient = spClient;

OData.read({
    requestUri: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('AppTest')/items?$select=Title",
},
function (data) {
    console.dir(data);

    changeTitle(data.results);
});

function changeTitle(results) {
    var id = results[0].__metadata.id;
    results[0].Title = "new title";

    OData.request({
        requestUri: results[0].__metadata.uri, //THE FIX
        method: "MERGE",
        data: results[0]
    });
}
});
```